# Dynamic datagrid columns in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript

I have `<mx:DataGrid>` in my system like the following.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="testDG">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="name" dataField="name">
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="measure" dataField="measure">
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

It has two columns, `name` and `measure`. I want to add another number of columns and it's data in the datagrid as respect to `measure`.

So, it looks like:

```
name  measure  1-Aug  2-Aug   3-Aug ...

abc   ggggg    20      22      24   ...
xyz   fffff    21      19      20   ...
pqr   hhhhh    30      21      13   ...

...    ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I want to add `date` wise result followed by `measure` column dynamically. 
 So, is it possible? How can I add dynamic columns after measures in Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
// Get current columns here.
var cols: Array = grid.columns;

var col1:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
col1.headerText = "1-Aug";
col1.dataField = "foo";
cols.push(col1);

var col2:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
col2.headerText = "2-Aug";
col2.dataField = "baz";
cols.push(col2);

grid.columns = cols;
```

If you want to add from 1-Aug to 31-Aug and these datafield is like val1~val31, how about this?

```
var cols: Array = grid.columns;
for (var i:int=1; i<=31;i++){
    var col:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
    col.headerText = i.toString()+"-Aug";
    col.dataField = "val"+i.toString();
    cols.push(col);
}
grid.columns = cols;
```

If you want to add other months, you should get from calendar instead of static 31 value.

**Update:** Oct 1 2015 16:40(JST)

For spark.DataGrid, there are different from mx.DataGrid a little.
Here is the code for spark.DataGrid.

```
// Get current columns here.
var list: ArrayList = grid.columns as ArrayList;
var cols: Array = list.source;

var col: GridColumn = new GridColumn();
col.headerText = "1-Aug";
col.dataField = "foo";
cols.push(col);

// Redefine columns.
grid.columns = new ArrayList(cols);

<s:DataGrid id="grid">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="type" width="100"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name" width="100"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: It's better solution than mine, since you're reusing standing columns, while I'm declaring them again.

Comment: Thanks and is this possible with spark datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

`DataGrid` has property `columns`. It can be used to set up columns dynamically. See example:

```
var columns:Array = [];
var nameColumn:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("name");
nameColumn.dataField = "name";
columns.push(nameColumn);
var measureColumn:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("measure");
measureColumn.dataField = "measure";
columns.push(measureColumn);
var newColumn:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("1-Aug");
newColumn.dataField = "1AugValue";
columns.push(newColumn);
...
dataGrid.columns = columns;
```

As far as I know, when you need to change column structure while keeping columns, that are already present, you need to create new array and declare the already present columns again.

Comment: No, `name,  measure` columns are static already there. Just want to add  infinite number of `date` columns dynamic.

Comment: Filling `columns` property makes `DataGrid` to recreate its columns according to the array provided. So if you, let's say, provide only `1-Aug` column, you will actually loose `name` and `measure` columns. If you wish only to add `1-Aug` column and not to touch `name` and `measure` columns, then I'd say it is not possible.

Comment: But there is dynamic number of date columns. For that i need to put it into loop.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You probably know the number of columns, their names and data fields.